# Is there any way to improve the speed of this NodeJS script?

Tags: node.js, bots, roblox

I have written a script to be used as an API for my website, but I want to improve the speed of it.

The point of the script is to calculate the total of a user's RAP (recent average price) of all their limited items on ROBLOX.

It takes 3.2 seconds to gather over 42m RAP from the 'ROBLOX' user (the one with the largest RAP total), and I'm wondering if I can knock this down a second or two. Here's the code:

```
let request = require('request-promise-lite')

request.Request.defaults = {
    json: true
}

const RAP_API = (id, asset, cursor) => `https://inventory.roblox.com/v1/users/${id}/assets/collectibles?assetType=${asset}&sortOrder=Asc&limit=100&cursor=${cursor}`

const assetTypes = ['Hat', 'Gear', 'Face', 'HairAccessory', 'FaceAccessory', 'NeckAccessory', 'ShoulderAccessory', 'FrontAccessory', 'BackAccessory', 'WaistAccessory']

class ROBLOX {
    constructor(id) {
        this.start = new Date()
        this.id = id
        this.RAP = 0
    }

    async getRAPforItemType(asset, cursor = "") {
        let API = await request.get(RAP_API(this.id, asset, cursor))
        API.data.forEach(item => this.RAP += Number(item.recentAveragePrice) || 0)
        if (API.nextPageCursor)
            return this.getRAPforItemType(asset, API.nextPageCursor)
    }

    async getRAP() {
        let requests = []
        for (let asset of assetTypes)
            requests.push(this.getRAPforItemType(asset))
        await Promise.all(requests)
        return {
            RAP: this.RAP,
            time: (new Date() - this.start) / 1000
        }
    }
}

new ROBLOX(1).getRAP().then((RAP) => {
    console.log(RAP)
})
```

Comment: (disclaimer: I haven't bothered looking at the API you're using, this is just based on what I inferred from your code)

Your bottleneck is easily going to be the network requests here, so you're looking for ways to reduce how long they take altogether.

Currently you have it grab 100 items and then if there's another page make a new request and repeat until done. I'd suggest finding a way to assume that more pages exist, run requests to each of those in parallel, and handle any that don't actually exist gracefully. If you're in luck there's an API command to check the total first.

Comment: @Bligglenuber Yeah, I get that. The API operates on a 'cursor' thing, you can't display all the pages at once. But the one thing that urks me is they don't have a category that displays all item types, instead you have to request all 10 of them, It's ridiculous.

Comment: And here's full API documentation from ROBLOX:
https://inventory.roblox.com/DOCS#!/Inventory/get_v1_users_userId_assets_collectibles